# use API key to get geocode,but it said my key experied

Tags: r, api, geocode, googleway

I try to geocode batch addresses use googleway package, like "2105 Woodcrest Lane SW", but it said MY API key was experied. but I know we don't need to update API key every time once using it. this is r picture and my code here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlqwU.png)is the problem about URL signiture?Do I need to add my signiture here? but how?

```
DT<-data.frame(newdata$`level of care`, newdata$AddressLine1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(DT)<-c("level of care","Address")
write.table(DT)

DT$Address<-as.character(DT$Address)
mykey <- "api key"
set_key(key= mykey)
library(googleway)
lat = vector("numeric", length = nrow(DT))
lng = vector("numeric", length = nrow(DT))
#google_geocode(address = DT$Address[i], key=mykey)

for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) {
  coord = googleway::google_geocode(DT$Address[i], key=mykey)

  if (coord$status == "OK") {
    coord = googleway::geocode_coordinates(coord)
    lat[i] = coord$lat[1]  # sometimes returns multiple coordinates
    lng[i] = coord$lng[1]  # sometimes returns multiple coordinates
  } else {
    lat[i] = NA
    lng[i] = NA
  }

}

#add log lat to DT
DT$lat<-lat
DT$lng<-lng
```

Comment: are you sure the API key is not expired? Have you checked Google Cloud Platform >> Google Maps >> API >> Geocoding API. I use this package and anytime I run into problems it has literally been my API keys

Comment: we only need one API key right? it could be used like Map Ststic API, Geocoding API?

Comment: I checked. I haven't get an message or alarm that said my API was experied. and I have already generate a new one it is still showed the same in the picture I posted there. still experied

Comment: ok, i solved. it might be update delay